# How can I suggest ease of use in a logo?

Tags: logo, conceptualization

How would you go about making a logo that indicates the action/feeling of ease?

How could you make it convey that feeling for a products or app that company makes which is easy to use?

I've been thinking that I could use lines that are thin or making rounded edges or by using colors to convey this feeling by including a water concept.

These ideas don't always work with some logos or some fields so I'm looking for some insight to designing this.

Here is some examples to go with what I'm trying to explain.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

to more explaining :
now i making a logo for ERP program and the client wants to send this feeling ( the app is easy to use and simple ) to customers when they are see the logo

Comment: Can you please include some image examples to help visualize what you're saying?

Comment: Why do you think the jewellery logo and Nike indicate ease or easy to use products? I think it's quite an abstract concept to represent using a shape.

Comment: @Luciano
that's not my point .. i put this images as i think it's sending ease feeling

Comment: What do you mean by "ease feeling"?  To feel or to be at ease normally means to feel relaxed/unworried.  To me, using that word to describe these logos makes little sense.

Comment: @MohamedAhmed can you explain why you think the logos you picked as examples say 'ease' or 'easy to use'

Comment: Please describe a little more specifically what are you trying to represent. Is it for a brand you're developing? How does this concept apply to your brand/product?

Comment: i mean how to make logo sending a message to the client that this product is easy to use

Comment: now i making a logo for ERP app and the client wants to send this feeling ( the app is easy to use and simple ) to customers when they are see the logo.

Answer (score 4):

A commonly-used approach to projecting ease-of-use for a product in its logo is to try to project "friendly" and "approachable", often by using a childlike or playful line (less regimented), rounded corners instead of square or sharp corners, bright colours (although often softened somewhat).

Compare:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Both are by the same designer, but the second gives a looser, more playful feel, is not rigid or formal, and evokes speed, ease of use, approachability and even implies fun.

This is but one approach to try: there are hundreds of ways to approach something like this.

You can also consider a super-simplified symbolic representational approach in combination with a loose, playful treatement - compare the NVIDIA logo to the Oracle logo - both about highly complex systems with an enduser facing front end - but NVIDIA successfully communicates fun, energy, easy and vision realted all in one simple logo treatment:

[image]

And compare that to the Oracle logo, which really gets a good solid reliable trustworthy feel, with a not at all subtle Star Trek reference which implies "high technology", but not so much on the playful, fun easy score, though it does have a certain accessibility which saves it from feeling too much like a fully generic corporate monolith like Microsoft.

[image]

Hope this is of some help.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe a primary function of a logo is to indicate a product is easy to use.

Here is a google search: [Airplane manufacturers](https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=airplane%20manufacturer%20logo&rlz=1C1GKLA_enMX664MX664&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwif5OLvyqvbAhUPYK0KHdxEAacQ_AUICigB&biw=1280&bih=700)

Are the airplanes easy to use?

Is the logo a reference indicating any sort of easy or not easy to use stuff?

---

A logo for a brand should indicate that the brand is trustworthy, solid, elegant, fun, be recognizable, etc.

So you need to think about all attributes. Easy to use is probably not the main one.

I would probably send that feature to a slogan, not to the logo.